# Why json dont work?

Tags: java, json, libgdx

When I try to run my project my game crash with this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeValue(Json.java:372)
at com.mygdx.game.GuardarMundo.write(GuardarMundo.java:12)
at com.mygdx.game.Mundo.<init>(Mundo.java:71)
at com.mygdx.game.Strategy.create(Strategy.java:9)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

And the code is:

```
static int x,z;
static String type;
@Override
public void write(Json json) {
    json.writeValue("X", x);
    json.writeValue("Z", z);
    json.writeValue("Type", type);
}

@Override
public void read(Json json, JsonValue jsonData) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public static void setBlock(int x2,int z2,String type2){
    x= x2;
    z=z2;
    type= type2;
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: JSON does work.  Your title is invalid.

Comment: you are calling `write()` method before the `setBlock()` method and hence yout `type` is null.

Comment: it seems `type` is null here. as `x` and `y` are primitive type. assign `type=""` then check, is it throws same error?

Comment: no,i'm calling after the setBlock() `json = new Json();
  guardar = new GuardarMundo();
  
  for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
   for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    
    GuardarMundo.setBlock(x,z,"dirt");
    guardar.write(json);
    
   }
  }`

Comment: You haven't specified where to write the json to, so the `writer` field in your `json` object is `null`. Try using `json.toJson` instead of just calling `write(json)` with no context.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the source [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Json.java), if you call `json.writeValue()` from out of nowhere, you will get a `NullPointerException` because the `writer` field in the `json` object will be `null`.

It looks like what you are supposed to do is to call one of the `json.toJson(...)` methods. Those initialise a `writer` for you and then use it for various calls to `writeValue()`.